# New Site FeedMySheep

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, screen

I am working on a site at http://nissidesign.com/FeedMySheep/ and I put it there while I am working on it.  This is a twitter bootstrap site, and my question is I am trying to put the logo on the top left corner.  I can do that, but when I reduce the screen size the logo is not playing well.  Is there a way to hide the logo for mobile or other small screens?  I have searched and all the suggestions people had to hide it on small screens do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this to your css, it will hide an element with id `your-logo` on screen sizes less than 600px.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #your-logo {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

So you can just change the id to your actual logo element id and to the maximum screen size you want to display the logo.

Comment: Yes!  That does it!  Thank you!

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem